# Integral of Smooth Function is Smooth (Possibly Using Leibniz's Rule)

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Assume $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a smooth function where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open star-shaped set with respect to a point $p \in U$. I'm trying to convince myself that the function

$$g_{i}(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(p+t(x-p))\,dt \qquad x \in U$$

is also smooth. I'm hoping that

$$\frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(p+t(x-p))\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}t\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{j} \partial x_{i}}(p+t(x-p))\,dt,$$
because the right most expression is continuous and differentiable by the smoothness of $f$. So I would be done. However, I'm not sure the last equality holds. If $f$ was a function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ then this would hold by Leibniz's differentiation under the integral sign, but $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and not $\mathbb{R}$. So does Lebniz hold in this more general setting as well? If not, does the last equality above still hold?

Comment: You're missing a $\partial$. But you're also missing the chain rule, aren't you? But, yes, there's no problem using Leibniz in the multivariable setting.

Comment: Edits have been made, and thanks for the catch. Glad to know it works in the multivariable setting as well.